# opening port 80 on AWS

Tags: 14.04, iptables

I created a AWS EC2 VPS(ubuntu v14) on which I want to open port 80 so that my website can run.

But unfortunately, I am not able to open port 80.

For this, I first ran the command:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

with this is what i get when I run

```
 $sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I see, tcp dpt:http is ACCEPTED.

But when I run nmap to check port 80  it say port 80 is closed. See below:

```
$ nmap x.x.x.x -p80

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-27 09:13 UTC
Nmap scan report for ec2-52-8-104-113.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00038s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

**I am really stuck with this, please help me.**

I have even tried ufw, but that also did not help.

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that after allowing connections on port 80, I do not see www service but http service. Is there a difference between two? What I do not see is - dpt:www  but dpt:http.

Comment: See [Opening port 80 EC2 Amazon web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services)

Answer (score 2):

Your iptables rule is correct. With that rule, you are basically telling iptables to accept any incoming TCP connections to destination port 80 (http) on your VPS. Technically, this rule isn't necessary since your `INPUT` chain policy is set to `ACCEPT`, which accepts any packet that traverses that chain.

Your Nmap scan reveals that the port is closed. The reason for this is your VPS is responding to the Nmap scan with some sort of "port not available" error, resulting in the `closed` port status. If iptables were dropping the packets, you would see `filtered` as the port status.

Try running `netstat -anp | grep :80` on your VPS. If the output is empty, then you do not have a web server listening on TCP port 80. If you're running Apache2 as your web server, the command output should look similar to this:

`tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1970/apache2`

Answer (score 0):

It causes you going to wrong way when you working with EC2 on AWS,
Go to your EC2 console and click on your EC2 security group, in incoming section add HTTP (port 80) and save.

You can open HTTP port for specifying IP address or for everyone by IP address 0.0.0.0

After saving your security group, you must have access to your EC2 HTTP port.

Answer (score 0):

To open a port 80 on aws instance

goto instance

please cheak outbound rules..

if there is not open 80 port then

please select http and open 80 port

also there u can open port 443 for https